# Когда удаляется объект лямбда-функции?

Tags: c++, qt

Программа периодически отсылает запросы по последовательному интерфейсу. Код отправки запроса и приёма ответа выглядит так:

```
QModbusReply *reply = device->sendReadRequest(dataUnit, trans->getAddress());
QObject::connect(reply, &QModbusReply::finished, [this, reply](){
    //Обработка ответа
});
```

Этот код выполняется с заданной периодичностью в течение всего времени, пока программа запущена. Поэтому, теоретически, объект лямбда-функции должен создаваться бесконечное количество раз. Так вот когда он удаляется и удаляется ли вообще? Безопасно ли создавать лямбда-функции таким образом?

Comment: Формально его область видимости — только вызывающая функция, так что должен постоянно создаваться и удаляться. Но есть еще и оптимизатор...

Comment: @Harry, а вызывающая функция здесь в недрах Qt. И неизвестно, происходит ли когда-нибудь выход из этой функции. А может и Qt вообще хранит все соединения в каком-нибудь контейнере.

Comment: лямбда виртуально создаёт объект с аргументом конструктора `[this, reply]`. Далее вызывается оператор `operator()` с вашей обработкой. Так как предаваемые аргументы `[this, reply]` это элементарные объекты *(указатели)*, то оптимизатор компилятора не вызовет никаких деструкторов и может сделать просто, записывая аргументы в стек и вызвать оператор `operator()`.

Comment: Вполне безопасно, но создаваться будет каждый раз новый лямбда-объект. Вы можете создать лямбду (или слот в классе) в другой области видимости  и просто подключать указатель на нее - это гораздо быстрее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лямбда будет удалена, когда будет удален объект reply.

Если вы перейдете к соответствующему определению connect, станет понятно, что в данном случае в качестве объекта получающего сигнал будет выступать этот же объект.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]